# Display a blazor component in scaffolded Identity Login.cshtml page

Tags: blazor-server-side, identity

I'm using scaffolded identity pages for my Blazor Server application (in .Net 8.0).

I am trying to add some blazor components onto the `Login.cshtml` page but I did not succeed.

Is there a way to achieve this?